# Argument of type 'string | VNode' is not assignable to parameter of type 'VNode & string'

Tags: typescript

Ok, i can be very wrong but help me out here, 
I am getting this error

> Argument of type 'string | VNode' is not assignable to parameter of type 'VNode & string'.
>     Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'VNode & string'.
>       Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'VNode'.

When i try to do this

```
addChild(child: VNode | string) {
    this._children.push(child);
    return 1
}
```

VNode Interface is like this

```
interface VNode {
readonly _tagName: string;
_attrs: {};
_children: VNode[] | string[];
 }
```

I recently shifted to TS, i can be very much wrong but help me out here....

Comment: `_children: (VNode | string)[]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You type for the `_children` property seems wrong, you want it to be an **`Array OF VNode OR string`** instead of `Array OF string OR Array OF VNode`:

```
interface VNode {
  readonly _tagName: string;
  _attrs: {};
  _children: Array<VNode | string>;
}
```